# flutter: how to populate a dropdown box from an list of of object

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter dropdown box and would like to populate it. The data format that I have is:

```
[
    {
        "stateName": "Alabama",
        "stateAbbr": "AL"
    },
    {
        "stateName": "Alaska",
        "stateAbbr": "AK"
    }
]
```

I want the user to see stateName but save the stateAbbr

How can I do this

Comment: Have you checked the corresponding [doc page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html), is there any specific problem with that?

Comment: I closed it, if you think this isn't the duplicate of the linked question, please update your question and let me know, I'd be happy to reopen it.